# VB.Net - Is there any way to count the number of selected rows in a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

I need to display the number of rows selected in a DataGridView to a label whenever the user selected at least one. But I have no idea on how to do it. Also I want to know what event should I use.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of selected rows, you may use

```
Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
```

And then to display in in a label;

```
lblLabel = selectedRowCount.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `YourGridView.MultiSelect=true;` MultiSelect When the MultiSelect property is set to true, multiple elements (cells, rows, or columns) can be selected in the DataGridView control. To select multiple elements, the user can hold down the CTRL key while clicking the elements to select. Consecutive elements can be selected by clicking the first element to select and then, while holding down the SHIFT key, clicking the last element to select.
then you can use SelectRows.

```
MessageBox.Show(yourDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: Count is not a member of DataGridView.

Answer (score -1):

The Event you are looking for is the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx) event of the grid.

You should set the [MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx) property of the grid to `true` to allow multiple selections.
And to get the number of selected rows you can use the [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) property:

```
MyLabel.Text = MyGrid.SelectedRows.Count().ToString()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Data Grid Mouse Down Event

Dim CRow As Int32 = DataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
DataGridView.Rows(CRow).Cells(ColumnName).Value()
```

Comment: Will that work for multiple selections?  Does that even give the count of selected rows?  I'm not sure if this answers the question or not...