# How to count the number of selected rows in datagridview vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm a complete rookie. I learned so much from here but this one I can't find the answer to. I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2015.

I found this question, but the answer does not work for my application:

[VB.Net - Is there any way to count the number of selected rows in a datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820843/vb-net-is-there-any-way-to-count-the-number-of-selected-rows-in-a-datagridview)

I have a windows form application that has a single column datagridview that is populated by reading a textfile, line by line at runtime.

I need to display (in a label) the number of rows that the user selects in the datagridview control.

I have this:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
        Dim selectedRowCount As Integer
        selectedRowCount = DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
        lblNumSelected.Text = selectedRowCount.ToString()
    End Sub
```

Or this:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
        lblNumSelected.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count().ToString()
    End Sub
```

Both of these methods return 0 (zero) no matter how many rows are selected.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `DataGridView`, set the `.SelectionMode` property to `FullRowSelect`, then use the `.SelectedRows.Count` property.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned the lesson, to check every property of the control for clues.

Answer (score 2):

I am having no problem using

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
End Sub
```

Could it be you're only selecting the cells themselves and not the row selector on the left side? When I select multiple cells I get 0 but using the button that selects an entire row counts correctly.

Comment: You are correct, this was the issue. I have the row selector hidden because I have only one column and the list is not editable by the user.